# ASP.NET Session Timing Out All Users At Once

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6

I am having users report that they are being logged out all at once after certain idle time.

Looked at ASP session properties in IIS, double checked that New ID On Secure Connection is set to true.

Users were reporting all being logged out after ~20 minutes - I saw that in the Session Properties Time-out was set to 20 minutes so I have changed this to 2 hours and experiencing all users timing out after around 2 hours.

This is how I am starting my session:

```
    protected void btn_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Instantiate user class
        var aUser = new User();

        //Authenticate the user
        aUser = aUser.Get_User(txb_Username.Text, txb_Password.Text);

        //Check if user details are incorrect
        if (aUser.UserId < 1)
        {
            //Tell the user the details are incorrect
            Label1.InnerText = "The login details were incorrect!";
        }
        else
        {
            //Check if user is archived
            if (aUser.Archived == 1)
            {
                //Show popup error
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('This account has been archived')", true);
            }
            else
            {
                //User authenticated - create a viewstate using the users ID
                ViewState["userId"] = aUser.UserId;

                //Check if user has not changed their password
                if (aUser.PasswordChanged == 0)
                {
                    //Force user to change their password
                    pnlLoginForm.Visible = false;
                    pnlResetPasswordForm.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Set session variables
                    Session["User_ID"] = aUser.UserId;
                    Session["Role"] = aUser.Role;
                    Session["UserLevel"] = aUser.UserLevel;

                    //Redirect user to system
                    Response.Redirect("~/System");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I also have this in my Web.Config:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Expected Results:
I expect 1 user to time out after the 2 hour time out limit but not all users

Actual Results:
All users time out at the exact same time after the 2 hour time out limit

I have no idea where to start looking to debug this problem

Comment: How are you getting the aUser variable in Session_Start?

Comment: @JohnPete22 I have updated the code in my original post.

Comment: Thought I had a suggestion, but unfortunately it's not relevant.  I've never had experience with InProc other than knowing that's the method to trigger the Session_End event. If you use StateServer or SQLServer, it doesn't hit the event.  Anyways, maybe this will help: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/inproc-session-state-mode-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: Based on that article I read...when you set up the IIS settings to 20 mins or 1 hour (sorry, not too familiar with IIS), does it restart/recycle the application which would cause the session data to be lost (which in my mind would result in all users being logged out).

Comment: I have looked under the recycling settings and it is set to 1740 minutes so I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: Since you are hosting in proc session, it sounds like the application pool get recycled after 2 hours which cause all session get expired. Have you checked whether PID get changed before and after? Did you see any error message in application or system event log?

Answer (score 0):

Is your application pool recycling?  That will make it appear that sessions are all timing out at the same time.

Comment: Under recycling settings it is set to 1740 minutes so I don't believe this is the problem.